# How to isolate the current version of the library in android gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am developing an SDK that connects as a dependency inside other projects via gradle. My SDK contains other dependencies. How to make sure that the SDK dependencies do not conflict with the dependencies inside the application itself? How can dependencies be isolated so that the application does not even see them?

The problem is that the library starts using a dependency from the app level. And I want to make sure that the library uses only what was written in its own gradle file.

Example, SDK level:

```
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.2.0"
```

App level:

```
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:2.0.1"
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make sure that the SDK dependencies do not conflict with the dependencies inside the application itself?

You do this through [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)

> How can dependencies be isolated so that the application does not even see them?

This isn't actually possible to hide library versions from your app do to the way the gradle build system resolves dependencies.

So, the issue here is actually an expected one. Gradle resolves your dependencies and includes only **one version** in your final APK.

You can **help** gradle resolve the dependency by including the following block in your app:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    // use either applications, or libraries version
    // your build can't include both
    force 'io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.2.0'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had such a problem before, but here is some input.

The problem you are experiencing in Gradle terms is touching two topics - [dependency resolution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html) and [resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html). By default, the resolution strategy is as such - Gradle takes the highest version of the library found among sub-projects and artifacts.

You have several options for the [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html). You can force users of your SDK to use a higher version of the library.

```
configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'io.insert-koin' && details.requested.name == 'koin-android' && details.requested.version < '3.2.0') {
            details.useVersion '3.2.0' 
            details.because "Breaking changes within Koin library version $details.requested.version use version 3.2.0 or higher"
        }
    }
}
```

The idea for the code snippet above is from [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html).

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really what I want exactly. I want to use DIFFERENT versions for module level and for app level. Is it possible?

Comment: @VladimirFisher As far as I understand it's not possible (if it is possible, please share, I'd love to know). I've experienced the problem of conflicting dependencies between espresso and firebase before. I think if it would be possible, the Google team would surely resolve this problem in their libraries.

Comment: @VladimirFisher I see that the question is open for some time now. I once saw this workshop by Gradle team suggested on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfVPZ8b08xs&t=490s&ab_channel=Gradle I guess this video kinda proofs the point  (time code 8:10)

Comment: Thanks for this. But it's not working on the library level. App level overwrite it. If you will do this on app level, it works. But I need to do this exactly on the library level.